# REST API file upload with symfony2

Tags: file, api, rest, symfony, upload

I have a REST API which use Symfony2. I need to upload a file on my REST API and send this file on an other service. How I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to you use [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle). It is optimized for a few file upload javascript libraries and it supports Gaufrette, which will upload your file everywhere you want.

Also you can check [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/): it sends automatically your file to S3 or Azure.